# emscripten fails to build hugin package

Tags: wxwidgets, emscripten, hugin

I'm trying to build the "hugin" package (https://launchpad.net/hugin) with emscripten.
The cmake command runs fine in native Linux, but the equivalent emscripten command returns errors.

With g++ the following command finishes successfully (and following that I can build the executables with "make all")

```
cmake ../
```

With emscripten, the following command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/emscripten/emsdk-portable/emscripten/1.37.28/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake ../
```

gives an error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Avner

Comment: can you post the CMake file please? And which wx version do you have on the system?

Comment: wxWidgets isn't available for emscripten as is. You will need to compile it from source. You can see if this helps https://github.com/abergmeier/emscripten-gettext/tree/master/gettext-tools/examples/hello-c%2B%2B-wxwidgets